# Transfotm PHP SQL to Joomla SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I am moving a PHP page to my Joomla website and I was advised that I ***"should use Joomla's coding standards and methods for everything, this includes database queries"***

My question is:

How should I transform my old PHP code regarding Joomla standards:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `TABLE 2` WHERE Power=".$input->get('Power', '', 'RAW')." AND Poles=".$input->get('Poles', '', 'RAW')."";

$results = mysql_query($query)
or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) 
{
extract($row);
}
?>
```

This is the TABLE 2 contents. I use the values of each row as a variables on my page.

[image]

Comment: Teodor, please remember you can ask your questions on [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com), which is the dedicated Stack Exchange site for Joomla ;)

Answer (score 1):

Most importantly make sure to filter the input to disallow sql injections. Seems both your inputs are numbers (Power is a float and Poles possibly an int?). Also use the #__ - in table names, it will be replaced by the table prefex when you use it in joomla functions. Simplest way to transform your code would be something like:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$power = $app->input->getFloat('Power'); // use the correct function
$poles = $app->input->getInt('Poles'); // for the datatype you want
```

see [here](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JInput.html) for JInput docs

```
$db = $app->getDbo();
//short variant
$sql = "SELECT * from `#__table 2` WHERE power = "
  . $db->quote($power) . " AND poles = " . $db->quote($poles);
$db->setQuery($sql);
$result = $db->loadRowList();
foreach($result as $array){
  print_r($array);
}
```

It should be noted that there are more useful methods for retrieving the data, loadAssoc/loadAssocList for associative arrays, loadObject/loadObjectList for objects. Check the [docs for JDatabaseDriver](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JDatabaseDriver.html)

Alternatively you could transform the query to a "Joomla query" like:

```
$q = $db->getQuery();
$q->select("*")->from($q->quoteName("#__Table 2"));
$q->where("Power = " . $db->quote($power));
$q->where("Poles = " . $db->quote($poles));
$db->setQuery($q);
...
```

[Docs to JDatabaseQuery](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JDatabaseQuery.html)

Comment: Don't forget to escape the table name ;)

Comment: Hello again!

I tried to do it, but it returns an empty page :(

Comment: I tried - foreach($result) { extract($row); echo $some-variable}

Comment: OK, this is sort of meta code, I'll spell it out for you

Comment: Changed the foreach-block so it will print whatever is returned